# AngularJS ng-switch, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting utterly frustrated with this ng-switch situation in the code below:

```
<div class="UPLcontent" ng-model="uploadFiles">
    <ul class="UPLfiles" ng-repeat="file in uploadFiles track by $index">
        <li class="UPLicon"><i class="{{file.type | typeIcon }}"></i></li>
        <li class="UPLinfo"><span>{{file.name | html}}</span><span>{{file.size | fileSize}}</span></li>
        <li class="UPLtool" ng-switch on="toolActionStage" >
            <i class="fi-x-circle" ng-click="removeFromUploadList($index)"  ng-switch-default="delete"></i>
            <div ng-switch-when="progress">

                <div ang:round:progress data-round-progress-model="roundProgressData"
                    data-round-progress-width="30"
                    data-round-progress-height="30"
                    data-round-progress-outer-circle-width="3"
                    data-round-progress-inner-circle-width="0"
                    data-round-progress-outer-circle-radius="10"
                    data-round-progress-inner-circle-radius="0"
                    data-round-progress-label-font="0pt Arial"
                    data-round-progress-outer-circle-background-color="red"
                    data-round-progress-outer-circle-foreground-color="#67CB8C"
                    data-round-progress-inner-circle-color="#505769"
                    data-round-progress-label-color="#67CB8C"
                    ></div>
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

My ng-switch-default displays just fine but when it comes to displaying the "progress" switch I get a blank container... I have tried it every which way and I can't get it to work properly. Any pointers?

UPDATE:

HEre is the round progressive bar directive, what's messing up???

```
angular.module('angular.directives-round-progress', []).directive('angRoundProgress', [function () {
  var compilationFunction = function (templateElement, templateAttributes, transclude) {
    if (templateElement.length === 1) {
      var node = templateElement[0];

      var width = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-width') || '400';
      var height = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-height') || '400';

      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('data-round-progress-model', node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-model'));

      node.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, node);

      var outerCircleWidth = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-outer-circle-width') || '20';
      var innerCircleWidth = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-inner-circle-width') || '5';

      var outerCircleBackgroundColor = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-outer-circle-background-color') || '#505769';
      var outerCircleForegroundColor = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-outer-circle-foreground-color') || '#12eeb9';
      var innerCircleColor = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-inner-circle-color') || '#505769';
      var labelColor = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-label-color') || '#12eeb9';

      var outerCircleRadius = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-outer-circle-radius') || '100';
      var innerCircleRadius = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-inner-circle-radius') || '70';

      var labelFont = node.getAttribute('data-round-progress-label-font') || '50pt Calibri';

      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, instanceElement, instanceAttributes, controller) {
          var expression = canvas.getAttribute('data-round-progress-model');
          scope.$watch(expression, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            // Create the content of the canvas
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

            // The "background" circle
            var x = width / 2;
            var y = height / 2;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, parseInt(outerCircleRadius), 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            ctx.lineWidth = parseInt(outerCircleWidth);
            ctx.strokeStyle = outerCircleBackgroundColor;
            ctx.stroke();

            // The inner circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, parseInt(innerCircleRadius), 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            ctx.lineWidth = parseInt(innerCircleWidth);
            ctx.strokeStyle = innerCircleColor;
            ctx.stroke();

            // The inner number
            ctx.font = labelFont;
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            ctx.fillStyle = labelColor;
            ctx.fillText(newValue.label + '%', x, y);

            // The "foreground" circle
            var startAngle = - (Math.PI / 2);
            var endAngle = ((Math.PI * 2 ) * newValue.percentage) - (Math.PI / 2);
            var anticlockwise = false;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, parseInt(outerCircleRadius), startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);
            ctx.lineWidth = parseInt(outerCircleWidth);
            ctx.strokeStyle = outerCircleForegroundColor;
            ctx.stroke();
          }, true);
        },
        post: function postLink(scope, instanceElement, instanceAttributes, controller) {}
      };
    }
  };

  var roundProgress = {
    compile: compilationFunction,
    replace: true
  };
  return roundProgress;
}]);
```

Comment: And have you inspected the document to see whether it's an AngularJS problem or a problem with your progress bar?

Comment: I did and there are no error thrown... nothing! The program bar works elsewhere

Comment: Could you build a plunker?

Comment: why dont you use the simplest way, without on, just ng-switch="toolActionStage"

Comment: inspect the value of your variable `toolActionStage` ... it might not be what you think it is. For example, `ng-repeat` creates isolate scopes, or you could have another directive creating child scopes...

Comment: I did and it's not the issue

Comment: The simplest solution if to use two ng-shows instead of the ng-switch, since the directive can't handle new scopes correctly.

Comment: @tasseKATT tried that it doesn't work either!

Comment: Yes it does. I've tried it.

Comment: @tasseKATT so please post code or a plunker because it doesn't work for me...

Comment: You said it works elsewhere. If it works without `ng-show` it will work with `ng-show`, since it just modifies the CSS. Replace `ng-switch-when="progress"` with `ng-show="true"`. If it doesn't work, you have another problem.

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-switch` creates a new scope and the directive is not handling it correctly.

You can see this easily by adding `debugger` to the post function and looking at the contents of `scope`.

If you run the directive without `ng-switch`, `roundProgressData` is in `scope` as expected.

In your case, `roundProgressData` can be found in `scope.$parent`.

UPDATE 2:

I agree with tasseKATT: just use `ng-show` instead. Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/masa671/m63ej0hf/

Comment: so do I pass $parent.roundProgressData to the directive??

Comment: how do you add debugger to the post function?? @masa

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `ng-switch on="toolActionStage"` with `ng-switch="toolActionStage"`. As far as I knowthe syntax you have right now is invalid.

Comment: It is valid, and from inspecting the source code, there is no difference between `ng-switch="x"` and `ng-switch on="x"`.